# Entanglement state preparation by using amplitude values

Tags: entanglement, qiskit

I have an algorithm that uses QRAM, after accessing the given QRAM that store M d-dimensional classical vectors, the state of the index register and the data register become entangled. But for now I don't have the QRAM black box, I just initialize the state of both systems by providing an array value to the registers at once using initialize function that exists in the qiskit module. 
My question is I have assigned the value 0 for non-visible basis. Is that ok?

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about the qRAM for encoding real numbers in amplitudes of a quantum system yes. Basically, you assume without loss of generalities that your problem/vector is of size a power of 2. But if your problem is not exactly of this type, we just pad with 0s. When you apply a quantum algorithm, you just need to be sure you are doing the computation you want.

Comment: Yes, sir thank you very much !!! that is what i want, encoding real number vectors to the amplitude. But as the dimension of the vector increased the result will be not expected. The algorithm that i want is to estimate the Euclidean distance between a single and a set of point (by taking the average).

Comment: The swap Test adapted for distance ?

Comment: Yes sir, when the number of points in the set and or the number of dimension is increased i loose a lot. What shall i do ?? I am in big trouble!!

Comment: I do not know the details about your experiments but first take it as some sort of results and don't panic. Next you can just try to reach people that can help.

Comment: Thank you every one!! I found it. Since the algorithm uses swap gate I was wrong on selecting the qubits that exchanged.

Comment: @Aman You mean that if we have our vectors requiring 3 qubits, the first on (q1,q2,q3) and the second (q4,q5,q6), you mean that we should swap (q1,q6), (q2,q5) and (q3,q4) instead of (q1,q4), (q2,q5), (q3,q6)?

Comment: No, in case of pure swap-test evaluation or cosine simillarity the swapping is straight forward, since both the vectors have equal number of qubits i.e. (q3,q6) ... (q1,q4). But incase of euclidean distance estimator algortihm the quantum state that are going to be exchanged usually doesnot have equal number of qubits. To exhange them we must start from the last indexes of the larger one and swap the qubits until we finish the smaller qubits exchanged. Let we have (q1,q2) and (q3, q4, q5) then we swap (q5,q2) and (q4,q1). This works 4 me, though the error of prediction is not very minimum.